# plot multiple dictionaries/dataframes in a single linear graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am collecting the data from some source in multiple dictionaries like below

```
d1={'01-01-2018':15,'02-01-2018':15,'03-01-2018':15}
d1={'01-01-2018':20,'02-01-2018':25,'03-01-2018':56}
d1={'01-01-2018':10,'02-01-2018':14,'03-01-2018':45}
d1={'01-01-2018':18,'02-01-2018':15,'03-01-2018':15}
```

Every dictionary is having Date and Values.Now I want to convert them into dataframe and then plot in a single linear graph (with 4 lines for `d1,d2,d3,d4`, `x axis` - Date, `y axis` - Value)

If multiple dictionaries are not convenient for plotting in a single graph, I can collect then in other suitable data structure (List)

Comment: Did you mean `d1 = ...` `d2 = ...` etc.? Now it simply overrides `d1` four times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d1': d1, 'd2': d2, 'd3': d3, 'd4': d4})
df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(df.index)).plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!.That works. Though collecting data dictionaries and naming them (when i dont know how many i need to build). Is there any other way (dictionary/list) to collect the data dynamically and plot them.

Comment: If you don't know how many lines to build and don't mind the names; You can collect them in a list and start from there. `lst = [d1, d2, d3, d4]; pd.DataFrame(lst).T.plot()`. This wouldn't give you meaningful legend as a named dictionaries, only `1,2,3,4...` if this fulfill your need.